# PHP Framework for large scale data intensive web development

Tags: php

I would like to know what would be the best MVC framework that can be used give these parameters

1. Ability to handle large DB
2. easy to use and configure
3. secure(session encryption, etc)
4. high performance
5. Available support(community)
6. ability to handle AJAX would be an added benefit, but not critical

I have been looking all over the web with conflicting results.

Please give your views, Efforts appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: Handling large databases is not really a function of the framework, but of the database. Pretty much any framework satisfies all your needs, except possibly for the available support.

Comment: Zend ftw. FYI your question is hard to answer objectively. plenty of frameworks can claim to do what you need. to improve it, you might want to specify some actual numbers and be more specific, like how many tables and records is a large db? what type of security is important? what level of support do you need? (community, corporate, enterprise?)

Comment: I use PHP for my framework. It can connect to various types of databases, work with web services, parse XML, and all that goodness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/). I like the way it designed. And they claim the performance of the framework is outstanding (here is the [Yii performance comparison](http://www.yiiframework.com/performance) to other PHP frameworks).

If you want to use framework for highloaded website, you can go with any framework you prefer. The bottleneck in highloaded applications is usually a database, so you will have to use different kind of caching mechanisms. Yii [supports different kind of caches](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApcCache)

To optimize complex SQL queries in Yii, don't use it's [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/), but use [DAO](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao) instead.

There is no obvious answer though.

Answer (score 0):

What about Simple PHP Framework?

http://clickontyler.com/simple-php-framework/